# cleaning up jquery css changes trying to make it one line

Tags: jquery

is there a way I can clean up this jquery css change? something like having all the css changes is on one .css()

```
 $('#container img')
               .css("opacity","1")
               .css("width","339px")
               .css("height", "211px");
```

Comment: Can you not make it a class instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#container img').css({
  opacity: 1,
  width: "339px",
  height: "211px"
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I would add a CSS class.

```
$('#container img').addClass("foo");
```

where

```
.foo{
   opacity: 1;
   width: 399px;
   height: 211px;
}
```

This technique is called Stateful CSS and is very useful for manipulating UI's: http://timgthomas.com/2012/05/mute-your-asynchronous-uis-with-stateful-css/

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

```
$('#container img').css({opacity: 1, width: "339px", height: "211px" })
```